# Chart не подымается график

Tags: c#, диаграммы

Когда один из столбов становится достаточно высоким, необходимо чтобы график рос вместе с ним, как это реализовать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Обновление**

Для построение гистограммы использую класс chart, когда один из столбов достигает верхней границы контейнера, то он уходит дальше за границы, как сделать так, чтоб по оси Y график автоматически масштабировался выше, при достижения одного из столбов границы?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    int y = 0;

    }    
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.chart2.Series.Clear();
        chart2.BorderlineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.DashDot;
        string seriesArray2 = "Кава";
        string seriesArray3 = "Вода";
        string seriesArray1 = "Кофе";
        Series series1 = this.chart2.Series.Add(seriesArray1);
        series1.LabelBackColor = Color.Pink;
        this.chart2.Palette = ChartColorPalette.Grayscale;
        this.chart2.Series[0].Points.AddXY(10, +1);
        this.chart2.Series[0].Points[0].Color = Color.Red;
        Series series2 = this.chart2.Series.Add(seriesArray2);
        this.chart2.Palette = ChartColorPalette.Chocolate;          
        this.chart2.Series[1].Points.AddXY(10, y+10);
        this.chart2.Series[1].Points[0].Color = Color.Pink;
        Series series3 = this.chart2.Series.Add(seriesArray3);
        this.chart2.Palette = ChartColorPalette.Excel;    
        y += 20;
    }
}
```

Comment: Уверен, ответ будет проще дать, если вы опубликуете проблемный код, с помощью которого можно будет воспроизвести проблему. (См. также [mcve])

Comment: Какой это контрол Chart, из какой библиотеки? Или приведите полное название класса, со всем пространствами имён.

Comment: Нативная библиотека VS 2012